# Passing in a date variable or check if no date is passed in then use getdate()

Tags: sql, variable-assignment

I would like to pass in a date variable using sqlcmd and do a checking condition where if there is no date passing in, then set the variable to getdate().
Can anyone advise me on this? Thank you. Below is my sql script.( the getdate() part should be modify)

```
--Declare variable to store back up file location
DECLARE @DBBackupFile as nvarchar(128);

SET @DBBackupFile = N'C:\sqlbackup\MOL_POSHistory\MOL_POSHistory_backup_' + convert(varchar(12),(year(GETDATE()) * 10000) + (month(GETDATE()) * 100) + Day(GETDATE()) -4 ) + N'0201.bak';

--Retrive the Logical file name of the database from backup.
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = @DBBackupFile
GO

--Make Database to single user Mode
ALTER DATABASE [MOL_POSHistory]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

--Restore Database
DECLARE @DBBackupFile as nvarchar(128);

SET @DBBackupFile = N'C:\sqlbackup\MOL_POSHistory\MOL_POSHistory_backup_' + convert(varchar(12),(year(GETDATE()) * 10000) + (month(GETDATE()) * 100) + Day(GETDATE()) -4 ) + N'0201.bak';

USE master;

RESTORE DATABASE [MOL_POSHistory] FROM DISK = @DBBackupFile WITH FILE = 1,

MOVE N'MOL_POSHistory' TO N'D:\SQLData01\MOL_POSHistory.mdf',

MOVE N'MOL_POSHistory_log' TO N'F:\SQLLog\MOL_POSHistory.ldf',

NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 10

--Set database to multi user mode
ALTER DATABASE [MOL_POSHistory] SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call the SQLCMD like this making use of the –v parameter:

```
// Date format is YYYYMMDD

sqlcmd -S YOUR_SERVER -v inputDate="20010101" -i "YOUR_INPUT_FILE" -E
```

You can access the parameters passed in by SQLCMD (`inputDate` in this example) like this:

```
DECLARE @inputDate NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @date DATETIME



SET @inputDate = '$(inputDate)'



IF (LEN(ISNULL(@inputDate, '')) = 0) BEGIN

        SET @date = GETDATE()

       PRINT 'Using default date'

END

ELSE BEGIN

        SET @date = @inputDate

        PRINT 'Using varaible date'

END
```

Comment: No problems - please remember to mark the answer correct if it solves your problem.

Comment: not add a comment, but press the "tick" icon under the answer score (on the top left hand side, near the answer)

Comment: Hi sorry for asking again...i try to run the script but it return me an error on : Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string for SET @ date = @ inputDate

Comment: can you update the question to include your SQLCMD statement?

Comment: SQLCMD -S 172.16.23.84 -v inputDate="20120622" -i "date.sql" -E

Comment: I tried the date using the sample above and it worked for me. You can use the -e (case is important) to output the result query which should help with debugging.